# Apache mod_wsgi import error-No module found

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have been trying to get an application written in Django working with Apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi with Django 1.3 and Python 2.7.2 - but it is not working at all. I have been working on for some time too - and it is working on dev-server perfectly. But I am unable to put in the production env (apahce).

My Apache Error logs shows the following:

```
[error] ['C:\\\\Python27\\\\lib\\\\site-packages\\\\django_tinymce-1.5.1a2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\\\windows\\\\system32\\\\python27.zip', 'C:\\\\Python27\\\\Lib', 'C:\\\\Python27\\\\DLLs', 'C:\\\\Python27\\\\Lib\\\\lib-tk', 'C:\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Apache2.2', 'C:\\\\Apache Software Foundation\\\\Apache2.2\\\\bin', 'C:\\\\Python27', 'C:\\\\Python27\\\\lib\\\\site-packages', 'C:\\\\Python27\\\\lib\\\\site-packages\\\\PIL', 'C:/wsgi_app/django.wsgi', 'path4', 'C:/workspace/MB/src/', 'C:/Django-1.3']
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7608): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/wsgi_app/django.wsgi'............

[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     s = unicode(s)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\functional.py", line 206, in __unicode_cast
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\translation\\__init__.py", line 81, in ugettext
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 286, in ugettext
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 276, in do_translate
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     app = import_module(appname)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Wed Aug 24 10:24:07 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named IWorks
```

The following is present in django.wsgi

```
import os
import sys

path = 'C:/wsgi_app/django.wsgi'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path2 = 'C:/workspace/MB/src/'
if path2 not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path2)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'MB.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

print >> sys.stderr, sys.path
```

And Apache Configs says :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wsgi_app/django.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/wsgi_app/">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am not able to understand why apache is looking for the module in site-packages.It is present in C:/workspace/MB/src/MB/IWorks? Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the normal but add to the .wsgi `path3 = 'C:/workspace/MB/src/MB/' if path3 not in ...` etc and see what happens?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. First change your paths to `'C:\\wsgi_app\\django.wsgi'` and `'C:\\workspace\\MB\\src\\'` in the .wsgi file only.

Comment: POSIX style paths should still work. Your first suggestion should actually be correct as they don't have the parent directory of where module is in sys.path.

Comment: Adding 'C:/wsgi_app/django.wsgi' to sys.path however is just plain wrong and shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0):

So an answer from both my comments as the OP hasn't replied i'll just assume one or the other will help.

[Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141) suggested in the comments that this one should be the fix:

add the following to the **.wsgi** file:

```
path3 = 'C:/workspace/MB/src/MB/'
if path3 not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path3)
```

I don't develop python on windows but I think the paths should be written `'C:\\workspace\\MB\\src\\'` not like `'C:/workspace/MB/src/'` *(from the django [docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi#dj_survey.wsgi) which aren't always correct.)*

Let me know if this did/didn't help.